# Strange behavior of reference in c++

Tags: c++

I'm little confused about reference type in c++, here goes my code snippet.

```cpp
class data
{
public:
    std::vector<int> Get() const
    {
        return vec;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4};
};

int main()
{
    data dat;
    auto const& a = dat.Get()[1];
    auto const& b = dat.Get()[2];
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output `a = 0, b = 1433763856` doesn't make any sense, after I remove the leading `&` before `a` and `b`, everything works fine. Now here goes my questions:

1. Since reference of reference is not allowed, but `vector::operator[]` do return a reference of element inside container, why no error thrown?
2. I know `data::Get()` function causes deep copy, but why I get the wrong value of `a` and `b`? Will the return value be destroyed right after function call?

Comment: `Get()` returns a temporary object. `a` and `b` are dangling references. *Will the return value be destroyed right after function call?* - After `;` on the corresponding line.

Comment: You return a copy of the vector. The reference is to items in a vector that no longer exists after the reference is made.

Comment: Why do you think there would be a reference to a reference? `dat.Get()[1]` is an `int&`, so `a` is an `int const&`. Removing the `&` make it `int const`.

Comment: If you make `data::Get()` return a reference it will work as you expect.

Comment: @Evg that should have been an answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'd prefer this question be closed as a dupe. I guess we have zillion ones.

Comment: @Evg it might be a dupe, but it's hard to say - the circumstances leading up to the problem can be diverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You return a copy of the vector, as the signature

```cpp
std::vector<int> Get() const
```

implies, as opposed to

```cpp
std::vector<int> /*const*/& Get() const
```

which would return a reference, this is true, but that doesn't really explain why returning a copy is a mistake in this situation.

After all, if the call was

```cpp
auto const& v = data.Get(); // *your* version here, the one returning by copy
```

`v` would not be dangling.

The point is that you're not keeping *that* copy alive by bounding it to a reference (as I've done in the last snippet).

Instead, you're calling [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) on that temporary, and that call results in a *reference* to an entry (`int&`) in *that* vector. When the temporary vector returned by `dat.Get()` is destroyed, that's the reference which dangles.

If `operator[]` returned by value, then not even the `a` and `b`  in your example would dangle.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Undefined Behavior!

Comment: @MarkRansom, why?

Comment: This is the problem with C++ - it's all too easy to shoot yourself in the foot with a perfectly innocent looking piece of code.

Comment: That's not a problem with c++, but a problem with the approach of learning c++ by inventing data structures instead of using existing ones with existing algorithms.

Comment: @Enlico the teaching of c++ is poor in many ways. I agree with you. But I also think c++ can (and is) do better.